# how i do reordring in datagridview by using the feature of drag and drop?

Tags: c#, winforms

How can implement reordring in winforms datagridview by using the feature of drag and drop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for asp.net you can use a nice [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) [table drag-n-drop plugin](http://www.isocra.com/2008/02/table-drag-and-drop-jquery-plugin/). As `DataGridView` is rendered as table. Download latest jquery file and include it in your page. Download drag and drop plugin file and include it after jquery file.

```
<asp:DataGridView id="myGrid" .....>
..............
</asp>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("<%= myGrid.ClientID %>").tableDnD();
    };
</script>
```

ps: plugin's home page contains fantastic examples

Comment: Hello Dear not in asp.net i will do in windows application

Comment: Please specify questions properly. I suspected this so I put "for asp.net.." in the beginning.